# Get real time updates from Microsoft Graph API (beta) Communication API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sharepoint, websocket, microsoft-graph-api

I am current using Microsoft Graph API (beta) to get Presence Status *e.g. Online, away etc.* in an spfx webpart (using React) using GraphClient:

```
this.props.context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient().then(async (client: MSGraphClient) => {
    let response = await client
      .api('/communications/getPresencesByUserId')
      .version('beta')
      .post(postData)
      console.log("Communication API Response: "+ response);
    this.usersWithPresence = response.value;
});
```

This is working fine, but to get updated status of a user, I have to refresh the page so another API call is made and updated presence status. I want to do it like this happens in **'Skype'**.

> What I need is suggestions about a mechanism that I can apply to get
>   real time updates in user's presence status, so as soon as user
>   updates the status this is reflected in  my webpart. I know I can use
>   `setInterval` or `setTimeout` functions to request for presence status
>   after specific intervals but for learning purposes i don't want to
>   request API this way again and again but rather getting updated
>   message from server like this happens using **web sockets**. How a web
>   socket sort of stuff can be applied with this API?

your suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today this API doesn't support any kind of subscription mechanism to when the status changes. There is a [uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/39456202-teams-subscription-to-user-presence-updates) entry you can upvote for it. That means the only way to get any changes is to periodically poll it. As for socket io, the only support today is for SharePoint lists, for any other resource you need to stand up your own infrastructure to relay the message.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!!..that would be great if i could find some useful resource about `stand up your own infrastructure to relay the message` part. To my understanding this involves some sort of **server app** configured on a particular port, configuring socket connection and namespaces etc. **service app** to fetch the data from api and send to the server and **client app** listening to `outgoing` messages from server.

Comment: I'd encourage you to look into Azure SignalR

Comment: i was looking into SignalR, when it comes about SignalR Hub that actually broadcasts the data to connected clients, according to my understanding SignalR Hub will contain the logic for getting user presence status from graph API. Since this API doesn't expose any webhook,so, in SignalR hub (server)  i still have to call the API repeatedly after specific intervals to get updated data, is this correct? in this case how it differs from calling API periodically from my javascript code rather than adding complexity of using SignalR?

Comment: First you have a proxy effect: if multiple clients are interested in the presence information of the same user, only your SignalR hub will be polling the Graph instead of multiple clients. This reduces your chances of getting throttled at scale.  
Second, the day we deliver webhooks for presence, you can adopt it easily as you already have a backend service to relay the information to clients (webhooks being a server to server subscription mechanism)

Comment: makes sense! Will go for this :)